# Android Bad image quality after scaling bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

Android Bad image quality after scaling bitmap;
This is the code I'm using live wallpaper application. There is constant background and how much I have use an image quality, the quality is deteriorating.
To improve the quality of images in the following code where I need to change?

Please could you help?

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.util.SparseArray;

public class BitmapManager {
private static final String TAG = BitmapManager.class.getSimpleName();
private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
private SparseArray<Bitmap> mData = new SparseArray<Bitmap>();
private static BitmapManager mInstance = null;
private static final Object mLock = new Object();
private Context mContext;



private BitmapManager(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public static BitmapManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = new BitmapManager(context);
            }
        }
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(int id) {
    return getBitmap(id, -1, -1);
}

/**
 * Not thread safe!
 */
public Bitmap getBitmap(int id, int scaleToWidth, int scaleToHeight) {
    String name;
    if (DEBUG) {
        name = mContext.getResources().getResourceName(id);
    }
    Bitmap b = mData.get(id);
    final boolean noScale = scaleToHeight == -1 || scaleToWidth == -1;
    if (DEBUG && noScale) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Scaling disabled.");
    }

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;

    boolean bitmap_updated = true;

    if (b == null) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Miss! Loading: "+name);
        }
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), id, options);
    } else if ((b.getWidth() > scaleToWidth || b.getHeight() > scaleToHeight) && !noScale) {
        b.recycle();
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Size changed! Reloading: "+name);
        }
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), id, options);
    } else {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Skipping, bitmap already loaded");
        }
        bitmap_updated = false;
    }
    // Do scaling only if original bitmap is bigger than needed dimensions
    if ((b.getWidth() > scaleToWidth || b.getHeight() > scaleToHeight) && !noScale) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Size does not match! Scaling.");
        }
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, scaleToWidth, scaleToHeight, false);
        b.recycle();
        b = scaled;
    }

    if (bitmap_updated) {
        mData.put(id, b);
    }

    return b;
}

public void clear() {
    for(int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
        Bitmap b = mData.valueAt(i);
        b.recycle();
    }
    mData.clear();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `options.inSampleSize = 2;` instead of `options.inScaled = false;`

i have faced same problem which solved with this.

Comment: I try to say it was worse. There must be another way.